# How to write descriptor when my BluetoothGattCharacteristic does not have one?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, texas-instruments

I'm making a app that connects via bluetooth to a sensortag cc2650, but when i try to write a value to descriptor of its characteristics, the characteristic do not has one, how can i configure it?

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback btleGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, final BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        Log.v("valores", String.valueOf(data));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status, final int newState) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            bluetoothGatt.discoverServices();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(final BluetoothGatt gatt, final int status) {
        List<BluetoothGattService> services = bluetoothGatt.getServices();
        for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
            if (service.getUuid().compareTo(movementServiceUUID) == 0) {
                writeCharacteristic(service.getCharacteristics(), service);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
```

This is the part that i connect to bluetooth device and pass the callback

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ItemListView item = adapter.getItem(position);
            bluetoothGatt = devicesMap.get(item.getId()).connectGatt(MainActivity.this, false, btleGattCallback);
        }
    });
```

This is the callback of after connected

```
private void writeCharacteristic(List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> list, BluetoothGattService service) {

    for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic charac : list) {
        if (charac.getUuid().compareTo(movementDataUUID) == 0) {
            bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(charac, true);
            //This descriptor ok
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = charac.getDescriptor(this.movementDataDescriptorUUID);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }

        if (charac.getUuid().compareTo(movementConfigUUID) == 0) {
            bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(charac, true);
            //This descriptor is null
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = charac.getDescriptor(this.movementConfigUUID);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }

        if (charac.getUuid().compareTo(movementPeriodUUID) == 0) {
            bluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(charac, true);
            //This descriptor is null
            BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = charac.getDescriptor(this.movementPeriodUUID);
            descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
            bluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the remote device added *Characteristic Client Config Descriptor* to its GATT table for the characteristics that you want to be notified? Just to double check it do the following: Put a break point where the services are discovered and find the characteristic in debugger. Find characteristic properties and see if characteristic property has this value: `PROPERTY_NOTIFY`

> Constant Value: 16 (0x00000010)

Alternatively, log the property value: `characteristic.getProperties()`

I checked Sensor Tag movement service from [TI wiki page](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/CC2650_SensorTag_User's_Guide#Movement_Sensor) and only *Data Characteristic* has Notify access. The rest of the characteristics has only Read/Write access. This means that you will never ever be able to write their *Client Characteristic Config. Descriptor* since they don't include one. Hence you will not be able to notified from these characteristics.